# How to load file into database table with MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

My new.csv file

```
cat new.csv 
;0;1;2;3;date
0;CHF;svájci frank;1;281,80;2017-06-15
1;EUR;euro;1;306,74;2017-06-15
2;USD;USA dollár;1;274,36;2017-06-15
3;AUD;ausztrál dollár;1;208,68;2017-06-15
4;BGN;bolgár Leva;1;156,84;2017-06-15
```

I have thought of this solution

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="milenko",passwd="newyork",db="dbase")
cur = db.cursor()
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/milenko/new.csv' INTO TABLE valami FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\'"
cur.execute(query)
```

But now I have problems

```
 cur.execute(query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/milenko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
```

How to solve this?I have checked database(exists).

Comment: First check if your query is running when you run the query directly on MySQL terminal.

Comment: Could it be due to the leading `;` on your 2nd line having nothing in front of it?

Comment: @Wondercricket Can you suggest solution?

Comment: I've never used this method before, but my suggestion is verify your columns match your table design. Like @BishwasMishra suggested, see what happens when you execute the same query directly into MySQL l

Comment: @Wondercricket Ok,I I will see my table design.